# Get product qty using product id Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am not able to get qty using product id.

```
public function hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter(array $params)
    {
        $vendproduct = $params['object'];
        $lang_id = (int) Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        $product     = new Product($vendproduct->id, false, $lang_id);
        print_r($product->quantity); exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get quantity by
$quantity = StockAvailable:: getQuantityAvailableByProduct($id_product = null, $id_product_attribute = null, $id_shop = null);